# Installing StimulusReflex in existing Rails 7 project using importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, stimulus-reflex

I'm stuck trying to get StimulusReflex working in my existing Rails 7.0.5 project with importmaps.

I installed:

```
gem "stimulus_reflex", "= 3.5.0.rc3"
```

importmaps.rb

```
    # Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/stimulus@3.2.2/dist/stimulus.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
puts "Import map loaded"
pin "stimulus_reflex", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:stimulus_reflex@3.5.0-rc3/dist/stimulus_reflex.js"
pin "@rails/actioncable", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/actioncable@7.0.8/app/assets/javascripts/actioncable.esm.js"
pin "cable_ready", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:cable_ready@5.0.1/dist/cable_ready.js"
pin "morphdom", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:morphdom@2.6.1/dist/morphdom.js"
pin "stimulus", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:stimulus@3.2.2/dist/stimulus.js"
pin "@rails/actioncable", to: "actioncable.esm.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/channels", under: "channels"
```

javascript/controllers/index.js

```
import { Application } from 'stimulus'
import StimulusReflex from 'stimulus_reflex'
import consumer from '../channels/consumer'

const application = Application.start()
application.consumer = consumer
StimulusReflex.initialize(application, { isolate: true })

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

I set up a simple reflex to test
reflexes/example2_reflex.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class Example2Reflex < ApplicationReflex
    def test
        puts "test"
    end
end
```

I have no errors in my browser console.  Terminal console shows:

```
StimulusReflex::Channel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
StimulusReflex::Channel is streaming from StimulusReflex::Channel
```

When I click my test button which calls Example2#test in my terminal console I get:

```
StimulusReflex::Channel#receive({"attrs"=>{"data-reflex"=>"click->Example2#test", "data-controller"=>"stimulus-reflex", "data-action"=>"click->stimulus-reflex#__perform".....
```

But then in red:

```
Reflex Example2#test failed: uninitialized constant ApplicationReflex
```

Which is kind of a big deal if Example2Reflex is not inheriting from ApplicationReflex!

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working a minute after I posted my question...

I did not add an application_reflex.rb file into my reflexes folder.

```
class ApplicationReflex < StimulusReflex::Reflex
  end
```

It works now with importmaps!  If anyone does have any improvements to the setup, please let me know.